# trying to build my own notification but nothing works

Tags: android, kotlin, android-notifications

I've been trying desperately to build my own notification to launch when ever i receive a message.
I'm trying to build a notification like a whatsapp incoming call that gives me the option to answer and ignore when phone isn't locked, and display a full screen activity when is locked.
I've also tried to silent my notification; the only way I managed was by adding a silent raw file.
Nothing seems to work, it won't vibrate when app isn't in foreground and it won't display over my lock screen when phone is locked.
This is my manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
```

this is my onrecive:

```
override fun onMessageReceived(p0: RemoteMessage) {
        if (p0.data.isNotEmpty()) 
            sendNotification()
         }
```

and this is my notification fun:

```
  private fun sendNotification() {
        val notificationManager =
            getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        val NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "MY_CHANNEL"
        val emptySound=Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE+"://"+packageName+"/"+R.raw.one_sec_silence)
        val fullScreenIntent = Intent(this, AnswerActivity::class.java)
        val fullScreenPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            fullScreenIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
        @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val notificationChannel = NotificationChannel(
                NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID,
                "desc",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            )
            val audioAttributes: AudioAttributes =
                AudioAttributes.Builder().setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                    .setLegacyStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION)
                    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION_EVENT).build()
            notificationChannel.description = "desc"
            notificationChannel.vibrationPattern = longArrayOf(0, 1000, 500, 1000)
            notificationChannel.enableVibration(true)
            notificationChannel.setSound(emptySound,audioAttributes)
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)

        }

        val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
        notificationBuilder
            .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_CALL)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setVibrate(longArrayOf(0, 1000, 500, 1000))
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.star_big_off)
            .setContentTitle("MYapp")
            .setContentText("content")
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setSound(emptySound)
            .setFullScreenIntent(fullScreenPendingIntent,true)
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(false)


        notificationManager.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build())


    }

}
```

I would much appreciate help, thanks

**EDIT:**
I have been testing on android 10,
I understand there might be a different way to achieve my goal on android 1o

Comment: I removed the firebase tag, as there are no Firebase APIs in use in the code provided here.

Answer (score 1):

So i can only help you with the lockscreen problem.

Try adding this on your notification channel

```
notificationChannel.lockscreenVisibility = Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC
```